# Display 2 decimal places, and use comma as separator in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to replace the dot in a float with a comma and keep a precision of 2 decimal places?

Example 1 : 105 ---> 105,00

Example 2 : 99.2 ---> 99,20

I used a lambda function `df['abc']= df['abc'].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}".replace('.', ','))`. But then I have an invalid format in Excel.

[image]

I'm updating a specific sheet on excel, so I'm using :  `wb = load_workbook(filename) ws = wb["FULL"] for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True): ws.append(row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found an other way to specify the float format directly in Excel using this code :

```
    for col_cell in ws['S':'CP'] :
        for i in col_cell :
            i.number_format = '0.00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
out = (s//1).astype(int).astype(str)+','+(s%1*100).astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
0    105,00
1     99,20
dtype: object
```

Input data

```
s=pd.Series([105,99.2])
```

Comment: Output type have to be float, cause it sent to excel sheet where it used by formulas

Comment: @MaherKebaier I think Excel will understand `,` just fine if you indicate it as decimal separator. Otherwise, I don't think you can keep the float dtype.

Comment: for some reasons, Excel remove the extra zeros (105 instead of 105,00) and (99,2 instead of 99,20)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series([105, 99.22]).apply(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}".replace('.', ',')
```

First `.apply` takes a function inside and

f string: `f"{x:.2f}` turns float into 2 decimal point string with '.'.

After that `.replace('.', ',')` just replaces `'.'` with `','`.

You can change the `pd.Series([105, 99.22])` to match it with your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaking something in here. In excel you can determine the print format i.e. the format in which numbers are printed (this icon with +/-0).
But it's not a format of cell's value i.e. cell either way is numeric. Now your approach tackles only cell value and not its formatting. In your question you save it as string, so it's read as string from Excel.

Having this said - don't format the value, upgrade your `pandas` (if you haven't done so already) and try something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51072652/11610186

---

To elaborate, try replacing your `for` loop with:

```py
i = 1
for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(row)
    # replace D with letter referring to number of column you want to see formatted:
    ws[f'D{i}'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    i += 1
```

Comment: The excel is begin generated daily by the python script. Users dont want to change the format of data manually for over 90 columns

Comment: Also, i'am updated a specific sheet on on excel, so i'am using :
`    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb["FULL"]


    for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
        ws.append(row)`

Comment: Can you share the piece of code, where you save the result?

Comment: NB the best would be, if you can add both pieces to your question i.e. how you read, and how you write back - they both are relevant. I think most people will assume you work on `csv` otherwise...

Comment: @MaherKebaier try now